# DataGridView not showing .bmp

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have snippet code to do the following:

-Two ListBoxes binded together. The first one to show a directory, and the second to show a subfolder.
-DataGridView to show the .bmp files.

I need to Set only one column called (Blocks), and add double click event to insert the dwg file.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private string rootDirectory = @"D:\test\Blocks";


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.DataSource = Directory.GetDirectories(rootDirectory).Select(Path.GetFileName).ToList();
        listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;
        listBox2.SelectedIndexChanged += ListBox2_SelectedIndexChanged;

        DataGridViewImageColumn dgvimgcol = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
        dgvimgcol.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch;
        dgvimgcol.Width = 250;
        dgvimgcol.HeaderText = "Blocks";
        dgvimgcol.Image = null;
        dataViewImages.RowTemplate.Height = 300;
        dataViewImages.Columns.Add(dgvimgcol);
        dataViewImages.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        dataViewImages.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
    }


    private void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // When an item changes in the first listbox, update the second listbox datasource
        var parentDir = Path.Combine(rootDirectory, listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
        listBox2.DataSource = Directory.GetDirectories(parentDir).Select(Path.GetFileName).ToList();
    }

    private void ListBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // When an item changes in the second listbox, update the datagridview datasource
        var parentDir = Path.Combine(rootDirectory, listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(),
        listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString());
        dataViewImages.DataSource = Directory.GetFiles(parentDir).Select(f => new { FileName = Path.GetFileName(f) }).ToList();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: you are binding a list of strings that happen to be file names. The grid is not going to know you want it to read those images and display them in the other column. Your data source should also contain an `Image` property.

Comment: thanks, @Crowcoder for replay. can you provide me an example

Answer (score 1):

[**Here is a demo I created for you on Github**](https://github.com/crowcoder/ImageGrid)

For simplicity I only demonstrated how to create a binding list of custom types that contain a property of type `Image` that the grid will know how to display. The images are stored in the project.

The view model has two properties:

```
using System.Drawing;

namespace ImageGrid
{
    class FilesViewModel
    {
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public Image Picture { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The form has code to create a list (specifically, I'm using a BindingList) of the view models. It reads all files in the "images" folder and builds a new instance for each one, creating a `System.Drawing.Image` for the `Picture` property. 
Finally, it sets the grid's `DataSource` to the list:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindingList<FilesViewModel> vmList = new BindingList<FilesViewModel>();

    string[] theFiles = Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "images"));

    foreach (string f in theFiles)
    {
        Image img = Image.FromFile(f);
        vmList.Add(new FilesViewModel { FileName = Path.GetFileName(f), Picture = img });
    }

    dataGridView1.DataSource = vmList;
}
```

Comment: Its work great, but I have an issue.I have two extensions files added to a folder that I present in DataGridView (.bmp + .dwg) when I add the .dwg files It crashed

Comment: I don't think that `.dwg` is a valid format for `Image`. I only glanced [at this](https://www.theswamp.org/index.php?topic=52567.0) but it looks like AutoCad has an API that can convert drawings to images so if you want to display those files you have more work to do.

Comment: yeah I know I'm was wondering if there any way to only display .bmp extension in DataGridView

Comment: Yes, you can check if the file name ends with ".bmp" in an `if` block. You should also probably be using exception handling too, for general robustness, and in case some joker named a non-image file with a .bmp extension.